# Removing space between fieldsets

Tags: forms, extjs, fieldset

I have a fieldset that contains a number of nested fieldsets that are dynamically added and removed.

However, I want the nested fieldsets to be displayed similar to a form e.g. with not much space between elements. However, each fieldset has a gap between then & I don't know how to remove this.
I tried using bodystyle on the parent fieldset but that had no effect.

I am using this method as it's easier to add/remove the "rows" in the form.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set bodyStyle on each of the nested fieldsets, not on the parent fieldset.

Depends on the parent fielset's layout but try `bodyStyle:'padding:0px'` on each of nested fieldsets.
On parent fieldset, you set `defaults:{bodyStyle:'padding:0px'}`

Comment: that had no change to the spacing. There is still evident space between each fieldset